FastAPI POST endpoint runs 4 times per single POST request
When running my FastAPI server, I have a POST endpoint that, for some reason, runs 4 times per POST request.
FastAPI backend code:
app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
[...]
@app.post("/create_new_session")
async def create_session(session_id: str, user_id: int = -1):
    create_new_session(session_id, user_id)
    logger.info(
        "created new session", extra={"session_id": session_id, "user_id": user_id}
    )

React frontend code:
function APP():
  [...]
  useEffect(() => {
    const dontUseSessionIdCookie = process.env.REACT_APP_DONT_USE_USER_ID_COOKIE === "true";
    datadogLogs.logger.info(`using session_id cookie: ${!dontUseSessionIdCookie}`, {'session-id': sessionId})
    const foundSessionId = dontUseSessionIdCookie ? undefined : Cookies.get('session_id');
    if (foundSessionId) {
      setSessionId(foundSessionId);
    } else {
      const sessionId = uuidv4();
      datadogLogs.logger.info('New session started', {'session-id': sessionId});  // Logs a new UUID
      Cookies.set('session_id', sessionId, { expires: 7 });
      setSessionId(sessionId);
      fetch(`${api_server_url}/create_new_session?session_id=${sessionId}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        redirect: 'follow',
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => datadogLogs.logger.info('Created new session', { 'data': data, 'session-id': sessionId }))
        .catch((error) => {
          datadogLogs.logger.error('Error while creating a new session:', { 'error': error, 'session-id': sessionId });
        });
    }
  }, [])

To be sure there was only one post request I've captured all HTTP traffic in Wireshark, and indeed saw only one request.
When inserting a breakpoint at the BE entrypoint I see the same src port for the request, the same session-id, and differences of ~800ms between calls.
This happens both locally, and when we run in production (over Herkou).
Any ideas??
Thanks :D
I've inspected both the frontend and backend logs and saw that there was indeed one log from the frontend and 4 logs from the backend. I used wireshark to make sure there wasnt some retry logic I wasnt aware of. I've inserted breakpoints in the entry point and manually inspected each ingress request to try and find clues.

If you run just the code you've included by itself and call it using curl - do you still see four requests?

Yep :
{"session_id": "4bcb4275-c0cd-4a79-a6a0-796a1eb82cdd", "user_id": -1, "message": "created new session", "time": "2024-04-24T17:15:32.125865+00:00"}
{"session_id": "4bcb4275-c0cd-4a79-a6a0-796a1eb82cdd", "user_id": -1, "message": "created new session", "time": "2024-04-24T17:15:32.126065+00:00"}
{"session_id": "4bcb4275-c0cd-4a79-a6a0-796a1eb82cdd", "user_id": -1, "message": "created new session", "time": "2024-04-24T17:15:32.126139+00:00"}
{"session_id": "4bcb4275-c0cd-4a79-a6a0-796a1eb82cdd", "user_id": -1, "message": "created new session", "time": "2024-04-24T17:15:32.126202+00:00

I also get one log from the BE that he returned 200 for (1) post
INFO:     127.0.0.1:59638 - "POST /create_new_session?session_id=4bcb4275-c0cd-4a79-a6a0-796a1eb82cdd HTTP/1.1" 200 OK

Since the name of your function (create_new_session) easily can be confused with create_session - you're sure you don't have any internal calls that call the wrong function, either as a callback or something similar? Have you seen what the call stack is for each of those times you hit a breakpoint at the start of the function? Create a small reproducible, self-contained example - I'm suspecting that there's code that we can't see which can be the cause of the issue.

Update: The bug was in the logger! When I've created the logger, I've added handlers each time, without checking if one already exists, as per: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745914/python-logging-module-is-printing-lines-multiple-times.

Neat that you found the cause! I'd suggest adding it as an answer with the relevant code, and then accept it yourself so it's answered as a possible solution for someone coming across this question in the future.

This was actually a problem with the logger, and not the FastAPI endpoint. The problem with the logger is a dup of this thread:
Python logging module is printing lines multiple times
